# Create Elixir Ecto data from multiple form elements

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

This is specifically me creating a custom date from from elements. I have a form that collects the day and month of birth of a person (I'm not interested in the year). So I use the following, to create the form entry for the `day_and_month_of_birth` element this post is about:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">Day / Month of Birth</div>
          <%= date_select f, :day_and_month_of_birth, builder: fn b -> %>
             <div class="col-md-3">
             <%= b.(:day, []) %>
             </div>
              /
             <div class="col-md-4">
             <%= b.(:month, []) %>
             </div>
          <% end %>
          <%= error_tag f, :day_and_month_of_birth %>
     </div>
</div>
```

In my model I have:

```
defmodule RocfDev.Registration do
   use RocfDev.Web, :model

schema "registration" do
  field :title, :string, virtual: true
  field :firstname, :string, virtual: true
  field :surname, :string, virtual: true
  field :day_and_month_of_birth, Ecto.Date, virtual: true
end

def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
   model
   |> cast(params, [
       :title, 
       :firstname, 
       :surname, 
       :day_and_month_of_birth
   ])
end
```

Currently when I post the form, I get the error `unrecognized date %{"day" => "1", "month" => "1"}`.

I suppose it's because there's no `day` and `month` field in the `registration` schema. My questions are:

1st, Since I'm not interested in the year of birth, is Ecto.Date still the appropriate type to use for the `day_and_month_of_birth` field?

2nd, How do I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two integer ranges `1..12` and `1..31`. But there are tons of limitations/constraints on their pair: `2` and `30` is invalid, etc. That’s why `Ecto.Date` type is still looking applicable here. To use it, one might force the year to always be, say, `2000`, and pass this value back and forth to your frontend, using the hidden field to “display” it and pass back. That way you could not care about `unrecognized date` errors: from now on you’ll get `%{"year" => 2000, "day" => "1", "month" => "1"}` here.

On the other hand, *just* day and month value is an incomplete information to verify the date, due to leap years existence. You can’t prove whether `February, 29` is a valid date of birth or not, without knowing the year. `2016/2/29` is valid, while `2017/2/29` is not. From this point of view, it sounds reasonable to quit abusing `Ecto.Date` and use just two range fields, both of type integer.